zsh: command not found (after setting package.json bin and installed global)
I tried to make cli app by typescript.
this is my code.
//package.json
{
  "name": "jihea-cli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "bin": {
    "cli": "./bin/index.ts"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "cli": "ts-node ./bin/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  }
}


/bin/index.ts
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(`!!! Please enter a valid name for your new app.`);
process.exit(0);

And I publish, and install global.
I checked by npm ls -g.
Desktop (main*) » npm ls -g                                                                                                                                    ~/Desktop
/opt/homebrew/lib
├── create-frontend-app@1.0.0
├── jihea-cli@1.0.1
├── n@9.0.0
├── npm@10.2.4
└── pages-project@0.1.5

But if I tried jihea-cli cli, it does not work.
zsh: command not found: jieha-cli

Please help me.
I want to make cli app that can be used by installed global.
Please help me.

change the bin.cli to bin.jieha-cli in package.json


zsh: command not found: jieha-cli ?

Actually it is working, just run this in terminal
cli

why?
It's a simple mistake in bin field of your package.json, because the bin field determines the name of the executable either in local or global like npx name or npm exec name or name in global

so you named of your executable as cli

If you have a single executable, and its name should be the name of the package, then you can just supply it as a string. For example
{
  "name": "jihea-cli",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "bin": "./bin/index.ts",
  ...
}

would be same as this
{
  "name": "jihea-cli",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "bin": {
    "jihea-cli": "./bin/index.ts"
  },
  ...
}

